# Minimum sum of integers not multiples of one another.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Question: Let A be a set of 7 positive integers that are not multiples of one another. Find the smallest possible sum of all elements in A.

I tried brute forcing the question: deriving the sum the 7 smallest primes to be 58(i.e. the sum of 2,3,5,7,11,13,17). However, i found a smaller sum of 55 with numbers the 4,5,6,7,9,11,13. However, I cannot seem to show in a neat way that this sum is indeed the smallest possible. Is 55 indeed the answer? Is there a way to show that it is?

Comment: I do not see any better way than brute force. I checked the sets with maximum element at most $30$, and found no better solution. Since a set with an element greater than $30$ would give sum at least $58$ (because $1$ is not allowed, hence the sum would be at least $2+3+4+5+6+7+31$) , This shows that you found the optimum.

Comment: Your solution is also the only one with sum $55$

Answer (score 3):

$55$ is indeed the answer. I checked it using an almost brute force approach, with some modifications:

1. Selecting the smallest number $i_1$, it can only be one of $2,3,4$, since $5+6+7+8+9+10+11$ is already more than $55$.
2. Selecting the second number $i_2$, we know that the total sum will be at least $i_1 + i_2 + i_2+1 + i_2+2 + i_2+3 + i_2+4 + i_2+5 = i_1 + 6i_2+15$ which means that we know $i_1\leq i_2\leq\frac{55-15-i_1}{6} = \frac{40-i_1}{6}$. Also, we can skip $2i_1,3i_1,4i_1,\dots$ when checking for possible values of $i_2$.
3. For $i_3$, we know that the total sum will be at least $i_1+i_2+i_3+i_3+1+i_3+2+i_3+3+i_3+4 = i_1+i_2+5i_3+10$ which means $i_2\leq i_3\leq\frac{45-i_1-i_2}{5}$. Also, we can skip $2i_1,3i_1,\dots$ as well as $2i_2,3i_2,\dots$ when looking for possible values of $i_3$.

Doing the same with $i_4,i_4,\dots i_7$ limits the search space somewhat, allowing us to see that $4,5,6,7,9,11,13$ is the only solution.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain why they consider my answer wrong?